# how to get text between keywords in unix variable

Tags: shell, unix

what would be the easiest way to grep text between two keywords in unix?

example :

```
unix_var="line1\nline2\n start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword ........"
```

i need to parse out text between start_key and end_key inclusive.

I tried to use sed but not able to get the desired result.

```
echo  "line1\nline2\n start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword ........" | sed -n  '/ start_keyword/,/end_keyword/p'
line1\nline2\n start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword ........
```

Please advice.

Comment: Your problem is that echo does not interpret `\n`. You need to use `echo -ne` or `printf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `grep -o`:

```
echo "$unix_var" | grep -o 'start_keyword.*end_keyword'
start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword
```

If you have `BASH` then you can do that in `BASH` itself:

```
[[ $unix_var =~ (start_keyword.*end_keyword) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
echo -ne "line 1\nline 2\nstart key\nmid line\nend key\nlast line\n"|sed -ne '/^start key/,/^end key/p'
```

that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
unix_var="line1\nline2\n start_keyword \n ..........\n end_keyword ........"
```

The easy way to extract the text between `start_keyword` and `end_keyword` is to use **substring extraction** or **substring removal**. An example would be:

```
text=${unix_var##*start_keyword} # remove from start through start_keyword
text=${text%end_keyword*}        # remove from end through end_keyword
```

The wanted text is now in `text`. Using substring removal:

```
text=${unix_var/*start_keword/}
text=${text/end_keyword*/}
```

The result would be the same in `text`.